# prevent options from being selected multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that contains 5 select elements and each one has the same options as the others, now I want each option to be selected only once so i need the code to achieve the following:

- when a user select some option in one of the select elements that option should be deleted or disabled in the other select elements
- when the user change his selection the old option should be added again to the other select elements or re-enabled so that the user can select it in another select

I've achieved both of these but my code only works for 2 selects but if i add more selects when the user change the select number 3 or higher the old options will be enabled in lower selects

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateDepartments2(event){
    var selectNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
    for (node of selectNodes){
        if (node !== event.target){
            for (child of node){
                    if (child.index != event.target.selectedIndex || child.index == 0){
                        var disabledState = ""
                    }else{
                    var disabledState = "disabled"
                    }

                node[child.index].disabled = disabledState
            }
        if (node.selectedIndex == event.target.selectedIndex)
        {
        node.selectedIndex = 0
        }
        }
    }


   }
</script>
</head>
<body>

Person Number 1
<select id="choice1" name="choice1" class="choice">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 2
<select id="choice2" name="choice2" class="choice">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 3
<select id="choice3" name="choice3" class="choice">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var selectNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
    for (node of selectNodes){
        node.onchange=updateDepartments2
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add all the selected options from all the checkboxes in an array.

Then traverse every option in other select box and see if value exists.
 Here's the updated js function for it.

```
function updateDepartments2(event) {
            var selectNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
            var x = [];
            for (node of selectNodes) {
                var opt = node.options[node.selectedIndex].value;
                x.push(opt);
            }
            for (node of selectNodes) {
                if (node !== event.target) {
                    for (child of node) {
                        if (x.includes(String(child.index))) {
                            var disabledState = "disabled"
                        } else {
                            var disabledState = ""
                        }

                        node[child.index].disabled = disabledState
                    }
                    if (node.selectedIndex == event.target.selectedIndex) {
                        node.selectedIndex = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/se1dofzb/1/

**Update 2 :**
I have reworked your function from scratch and please check for any bugs or clarification needed.

```
function updateDepartments2(event) {
        var selectNodes = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
        var x = [];
        for (var node of selectNodes) {
            if (node.selectedIndex != 0)
                x.push(node.selectedIndex);// Add index of all selected elements
        }
        for (var node of selectNodes) {
            for (var child of node) {
                //Traverse all option in every select box
                var disabledState;
                if (x.includes(child.index)) {
                    //If it is selected, disable it
                    disabledState = "disabled"
                } else {
                    disabledState = ""
                }
                node[child.index].disabled = disabledState
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code works but it has some problems, first you're comparing option values with option indexes, this assumes that the option value is equal to the option index so this will fail when changing the option values to a string.Second problem is the code should make an exception for option number 0 which is the null option so as to allow the user to select this in all selects and re-arrange their choices. i fixed these problems here https://jsfiddle.net/jde9vfh5/
one problem that I couldn't yet fix is when I reset all selects to the option 0 the last select i reset doesn't re-enable the option.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing the bug.
Here's the updated fiddle for your second part where option was not getting enabled :
https://jsfiddle.net/se1dofzb/1/

Comment: hmmm yet another bug, when you select the null option it re-enables every option !!

Comment: yet another bug, when i select an option it disables that option in all selects including the `event.target` one, anyways I solved the issue by saving the choice index and the select element that it belongs to in an array: https://jsfiddle.net/anh93e4w/

Comment: Well i thought that was the feature you required.
But anyways if it is solved then cheers.
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Call the function on change of the select and get the option index. Get all the select elements and disable the selected option in the select elements

```js
function a(e)
{
console.log(e.selectedIndex)
var k=document.querySelectorAll('select')
for(let i=0;i<k.length;i++)
{
if(k[i]!=e)
k[i].options[e.selectedIndex].setAttribute("disabled","disabled")
}
}
function d()
{
var k=document.querySelectorAll('select')
for(let i=0;i<k.length;i++)
{
var c=k[i].querySelectorAll('option');
for(let i=0;i<c.length;i++)
c[i].removeAttribute("disabled")
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

Person Number 1
<select id="choice1" name="choice1" class="choice" onchange="a(this)">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 2
<select id="choice2" name="choice2" class="choice" onchange="a(this)">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br/>
Person Number 3
<select id="choice3" name="choice3" class="choice" onchange="a(this)">
<option value="null">Please Select an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>
   <input type="button" onclick="d()" value="Reset"> 
</body>
</html>
```